# SQL Server 2008 case statement to count records and not another record with same date but different result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to count the number of id's where the Name and Eventname can have either 'Accept' or 'reject' for a value on the same date. How can i write a case statement to only use the 'Accept' value? i have tried many ways and still counts them all. Still counts the 'reject' records.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

example below:

```
select th.NAME, 
       COUNT(distinct th.HICN_CD) AS HICN_COUNT, 
       case  th.EVENTNAME 
           when 'accept'  then 'Accept' 
           when 'reject'   then 'Reject' ELSE 'N/A'
       END AS Event_Name
from #temp_hicn th
left join #temp_maxdate tm
   on tm.HICN_CD = th.HICN_CD
group by th.NAME, 
         th.EVENTNAME
order by th.NAME ;
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want conditional aggregation:

```
select th.NAME, COUNT(distinct th.HICN_CD) AS HICN_COUNT , 
       sum(case th.EVENTNAME when 'accept' then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumAccept
from #temp_hicn th left join
     #temp_maxdate tm
     on tm.HICN_CD = th.HICN_CD
group by th.NAME
order by th.NAME;
```

If you want to count distinct value of `HICN_CD` for accepts:

```
select th.NAME,
       COUNT(distinct case th.EVENTNAME when 'accept' then th.HICN_CD end) AS HICN_COUNT , 
       sum(case th.EVENTNAME when 'accept' then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumAccept
from #temp_hicn th left join
     #temp_maxdate tm
     on tm.HICN_CD = th.HICN_CD
group by th.NAME
order by th.NAME;
```

Comment: @Gordan Linhof - thanks for your help. it gets the accept count correct. still adds in the reject count if there is an accept as well. might not have explained that part as well as i should have to say i dont want an reject if there is an except on same date.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT TH.HICN_CD, TH.NAME, TH.EVENTNAME, TM.MAX_DATE
    INTO #TEMP_ACCEPT
FROM #TEMP_HICN TH
    LEFT JOIN #TEMP_MAXDATE TM
    ON TM.HICN_CD = TH.HICN_CD
    AND TM.MAX_DATE = TH.MAX_DATEID
GROUP BY TH.MEDICARE_HICN_CD, TH.NAME, TH.EVENTNAME, TM.MAX_DATE;

SELECT DISTINCT TH.MEDICARE_HICN_CD, TH.NAME, TH.EVENTNAME, TM.MAX_DATE
    INTO #TEMP_REJECT
FROM #TEMP_HICN TH
    LEFT JOIN #TEMP_MAXDATE TM
    ON TM.HICN_CD = TH.HICN_CD
    AND TM.MAX_DATE = TH.MAX_DATEID
    WHERE TH.EVENTNAME = 'REJECT'
    AND TH.HICN_CD + TH.NAME NOT IN (SELECT HICN_CD + NAME FROM #TEMP_ACCEPT)
GROUP BY TH.HICN_CD, TH.NAME, TH.EVENTNAME, TM.MAX_DATE;

SELECT * 
    INTO #TEMP_EVENT
FROM #TEMP_ACCEPT
    UNION
SELECT * 
FROM #TEMP_REJECT;

WITH EVENT_DUP AS (
SELECT DISTINCT HICN_CD, NAME, COUNT(*) AS 'EVENTS'
FROM #TEMP_EVENT
GROUP BY HICN_CD, NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
DELETE FROM #TEMP_EVENT
    WHERE HICN_CD + NAME IN (SELECT HICN_CD + NAME FROM EVENT_DUP)
    AND MAX_DATE IS NULL;

SELECT EV.NAME, EV.EVENTNAME ,COUNT(DISTINCT EV.HICN_CD) AS HICN_COUNT
FROM #TEMP_EVENT EV
    LEFT JOIN #TEMP_MAXDATE TM
    ON TM.HICN_CD = EV.HICN_CD
GROUP BY EV.NAME, EV.EVENTNAME
ORDER BY EV.NAME;